# Is it possible to remove excessive gaps/delays in i2c waveform on NodeMCU/Lua?

Tags: lua, i2c, nodemcu

Calling the following function gives me the waveform on the first snapshot:

```
function writeDac(addr, value)
  value2 = BitAND(value, 255)
  value1 = rshift(value, 8)

  i2c.start(bus)
  i2c.address(bus, addr, i2c.TRANSMITTER)
  i2c.write(bus, value1)
  i2c.write(bus, value2)
  i2c.stop(bus)

end
```

[image]

Joining two writes in one removes one of the gaps on the waveform:

```
i2c.write(bus, value1, value2)
```

instead of

```
i2c.write(bus, value1)
i2c.write(bus, value2)
```

[image]

So I wonder, is there a way to remove the excessive gaps between "start", "address" and "stop"?

Comment: Just a side note: Lua is an interpreted language.  It speed up development time and slows down program execution time.

Comment: I understand. Its just that one of the gaps seemed so easy to remove, so I wondered about the others. Its not a critical aspect of the project.